# If statement listing exceptions

Tags: python

I'm having an issue with this codebat question:

The parameter weekday is True if it is a weekday, and the parameter vacation is True if we are on vacation. We sleep in if it is not a weekday or we're on vacation. Return True if we sleep in.

sleep_in(False, False) → True
sleep_in(True, False) → False
sleep_in(False, True) → True

Here's my solution:

```
 def sleep_in(weekday, vacation):

     if (True, False):
         return False

     else:
         return True
```

And the result came back as:

```
sleep_in(False, False) → True   False   X       
sleep_in(True, False) → False   False   OK      
sleep_in(False, True) → True    False   X       
sleep_in(True, True) → True     False   X
```

I'm confused as to why it's wrong.

In my solution, I stated:

```
if (True, False):
    return False
```

And everything being True.

Can any one give me an idea where I am going wrong?

Comment: Well what on earth are you expecting `if (True, False):` to **do**?! Any non-empty sequence evaluates truth-y, so you will *always* `return False`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe it would seem like they believe that they should simply me listing the states possible for their input parameters and the actions to take for those states, like some form of implicit switch statement. There's a pretty fundamental misunderstanding of how python works going on here. They basically wrote out a truth table.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: they're maybe expecting something like Haskell's pattern matching to happen here, where they could enumerate the parameters and outcomes.

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz I'd never seen Haskell [pattern matching](https://www.haskell.org/tutorial/patterns.html) but yup, that's exactly what it looks like the OP expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> We sleep in if it is not a weekday or we're on vacation.

This is best expressed as a straight-up boolean comparison.

```
def sleep_in(weekday, vacation):
    return not weekday or vacation
```

Fair warning:  this will evaluate to `True` if either of those parameters are truthy.

Speaking of "truthy", the experssion `(True, False)` is a tuple, and since it is a non-empty tuple, it will evaluate to `True`.  For reference, [here is a list of all expressions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing) that evaluate to `False`. Anything outside of that list will evaluate to `True` in a boolean context.

Comment: Can you please explain a tuple?

Comment: The link provided in the answer above includes the section on tuples.  I strongly encourage you to have a read of it.